# facebook application: how to put html code like 'a href' inside news feed content? (After the newest api update)

Tags: facebook, deprecated, feed

After the newest Facebook update for publishing news feed, it seems that it doesn't support html code (like a href) inside the new feed content anymore

But I still see feeds with click-able link inside the content, how to do that?

below are the images of the feeds that have link inside the feed content

[image]
<sub>(source: [dchammer.com](http://code.dchammer.com/calvinc/feed1.jpg))</sub>

[image]

Comment: @Michel... isn't this coding question for facebook application?

Comment: Here is the solution: http://netodex.com/2009/10/28/the-new-facebook-streams-explained-and-simplified-using-php/ This works exactly as you want!

Answer (score 2):

Use the properties property of the [stream attachment](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Attachment_%28Streams%29) object. This takes a dictionary of key/value pairs, where the values can themselves be an object consisting of text and href properties. E.g. attach something like the following onto your stream attachment object in JavaScript:

```
var properties = {
    "Rating" : {
        "text" : "1797 points",
        "href":"http://apps.facebook.com/yourappurl/"
        },
    "Leaderboard position":{
        "text":"192nd",
        "href":"http://apps.facebook.com/yourappurl/"
    }
}
```

Will display the text "Rating: 1797 points" and "Leaderboard position : 192nd" on separate lines, with the "Rating" and Leaderboard position" text in light grey and the "1792 points" and "192nd" both as blue hyperlinks.

There are character of 50 characters max for the "key" part (i.e. the "Leaderboard position" segment) and 70 characters for the "value" part.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the answer to the question. Using properties will result in UNWANTED number ordering before each line: http://code.dchammer.com/calvinc/feedProblem.jpg As you can see in the image, there are numbering in front of each link. But what I want is href links inside some words in a sentence, which is shown in the screenshots inside my question :) I need your kind help!

Comment: It looks like you've generated the JSON incorrectly to me, especially given the suprious &quot; character. I've used the structure above here: http://apps.facebook.com/playfourinarow/ (click on "Post open challenge" to see a story). There's no numbering, and the generated format is of exactly the same type as yoru question.

Comment: ignore that &quot;.... btw when I click that "Post open challenge" it always return "Application response error". Tried in firefox + chrome + IE. http://code.dchammer.com/calvinc/fourInARow.jpg

Comment: Do you mind to make a page with either php/javascript containing a sample of workable news feed content? So I can try the file on my server and if it works then I can immediately accept your answer and pour my up votes on you :D

Comment: The error looks like it's on Facebook's end - I can see from my stats that users are publishing those stories. But I've put a demo page up which "works for me": http://games.core10.co.uk/connector/story.html

Comment: seems stackoverflow won't allow me to accept answers after the bounty ends... let me search some of your questions/answers which are worth for upvotes

Comment: Thanks Karl B. Now I know why there's numbering in front. No numbering format---   "properties":{"a":{"text":"b","href":"c"},"d":{"text":"e","href":"f"}}      Auto numbering by facebook-------- "properties":[{"text":"b","href":"c"},{"text":"e","href":"f"}]

Answer (score 1):

So I tried a href and instead of the usual html, I did some trial and error and found out it will work if written like this:

```
a href=facebook.com facebook
```

the key is the space between the link and the actual text you want to display. Without the space this won't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is specified by the meta tags of the page being linked to.  For more information, check out http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Share/Specifying_Meta_Tags

Basically, when the user posts a link to an outside site, facebook fetches that page, and looks at certain meta tags to come up with a preview of the site, including some text and a small image, if these are specified by the linked site.

So, I think you should be able to just include your href tags in your meta description, and you should be all set.  I haven't tried this with links, but that is definitely how you get the description and image to show up.